# try to get records from 4 tables using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables all are connected to each other via foreign key the problem is that I want to get records from all tables and count number of records present in 4th table as of now if there is no data in 4th table the query returns 0 records as of it should still pull up data with total_players from 4th table to be shown as  instead of not pulling any data below is the query i made sa of i remove the statement to count players it is working fine

```
SELECT tournament.*,
   categories.title AS category,
   categories.slug AS category_slug,
   games.game_name,
   games.slug AS game_slug,
   count(tournament_players.id) AS total_players
FROM tournament
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = tournament.category_id
LEFT JOIN games ON games.game_id = tournament.game_id
LEFT JOIN tournament_players ON tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id
```

`count(tournament_players.id) AS total_players`

Here if there is no players present in this table it should show 0 but when there is no players present in this table it does not pull records from other table where as the data is present in rest of 3 tables

Any one please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a `GROUP BY` missing?

```
SELECT 
    tournament.*, 
    categories.title AS category, 
    categories.slug AS category_slug, 
    games.game_name, 
    games.slug AS game_slug, 
    COUNT(tournament_players.id) AS total_players 
FROM tournament 
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = tournament.category_id 
LEFT JOIN games ON games.game_id = tournament.game_id 
LEFT JOIN tournament_players ON tournament_players.tournamentID = tournament.id
GROUP BY ...
```

Excuse me for mentioning this: test data would have definitely been helpful and the SQL code could have been formatted a bit better as well.

Comment: group by ?? ok let me put sample data